# HTML email stretching full width in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, stretching

I have an email that works fine in every email client except Outlook 2013. In Outlook 2013 the email stretches full width when it should only be 600px wide.

I've tried searching everywhere for a fix but with no luck!

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Scientific Data</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {width:100% !important;}
  .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%;}
  .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;color:#666666;}
  table td { border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
  p { margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
  ul { margin: 0; }
  a, img {border:none;}
  .symbolfix img {width:9px !important;height:9px !important;}
  a {color:#363636;text-decoration:none;} a {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);color:#006699; !important}
  .appleLinks a {color:#666666; text-decoration:none;} /* Stop iOS making times and dates blue */
  .ExternalClass * { line-height: 100%; }
  @media (max-width:480px) {
   table[class="wrapper"], td[class="wrapper"] {width:320px !important;}
   table[id="header"]{width:100% !important;}
   img[class="banner"], img[class="headercell"]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
   img[id="img-280"]{width:280px !important; height:auto !important; padding:0px !important;}
   table[id="col-left"],table[id="col-center"], table[id="col-right"]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }
   table[id="col-one"],table[id="col-two"],table[id="col-full"]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
   table[id="col-half"]{width:80% !important;}
   td[class="hide"]{display:none !important;}
   img[id="small-img"]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
   td[id="social-media"]{width:100% !important;padding:30px 0px 20px 0px !important;}
   table[id="prod-icons"]{width:25% !important;}
   td[id="gutter"]{width:25px !important;}
   td[id="gutter-small"]{width:10px !important;}
   td[id="break-top"]{border-top:1px solid #cccccc;}
   img[id="cont-title"]{width:auto !important; height:50px !important;}
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#e7e7e7">
  <!-- 100% table -->
  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
   <tr>
    <td width="600" align="center" class="wrapper">
     <table width="600" bgcolor="#e7e7e7"  class="wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td width="600" align="center" class="wrapper">
        <br />
        <!-- wrapper table -->
        <table class="wrapper" width="600" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
         <tr>
          <td class="wrapper">
           <table class="wrapper" width="600" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
            <tr>
             <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#cdcdcd"><!-- preheader table -->  <!-- end of preheader table -->
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- header table -->
        <tr>
         <td width="600" align="center" class="wrapper">
          <table width="600" class="wrapper" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#274a5c"><a href="http://www.nature.com/scientificdata/?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1507_Epidemiology_Usage_Driving&WT.i_dcsvid=%%LIST_ID%%-%%RECIPIENT_ID%%&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank"><img class="headercell" src="http://fastart.nature.com/1989_2015/header.jpg" alt="Scientific Data" width="600" height="84" border="0" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:22px;font-weight:bold;color:#b01b22;display:block;"  /></a>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="600" bgcolor="#ef763d" style="height:10px;font-size:10px;line-height:10px;">&nbsp;
        </td>
       </tr>
       <!-- end of header table -->
       <!--Title-->
       <tr>
        <td width="600" align="center" class="wrapper">
         <table width="600" class="wrapper" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
           <td width="600" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 28px; color: #363636; padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;"><strong>Scientific Data</em> おすすめのコンテンツ – Epidemiology
            </strong>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- end of Title -->
          <!--main body-->
          <tr>
           <td width="600" align="center" class="wrapper">
            <table width="600" class="wrapper" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
              <td width="600" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #363636; padding:0px 20px 30px 20px;">
               <em>Scientific Data</em> は価値のある研究データセットを掲載するオープンアクセスジャーナルです。研究データの広範囲な再利用を促進するとともに、データを公開した研究者にクレジットを与えることを目指します。<em>Scientific Data </em>は科学のすべての領域を対象とし、データのサイズや、研究主体の規模（主要な研究コンソーシアム、研究室、個人単位）に関わらず、投稿を受け付けています。<br /><br />
               <em>Scientific Data</em> で出版される<a href="http://www.nature.com/sdata/for-authors/submission-guidelines?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%25%25LIST_ID%25%25-%25%25RECIPIENT_ID%25%25&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank" style="color:#006699;">Data Descriptors</a> は、科学的なデータセットをくわしく記述する新しいタイプのコンテンツで、公開されたデータを読者が理解しやすく、再利用しやすい形で構成されています。<br /><br />
               あなたのご関心分野で、最近特に注目されているData Descriptorを選んでご紹介します。是非ご閲覧ください。また、最新の研究成果をお届けする <em>Scientific Data</em> コンテンツアラートに是非ご登録ください。
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- end of body -->
          <!--Button -->
          <tr>
           <td width="600" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">
            <table bgcolor="#ef763d" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:20px;color:#ffffff;padding: 10px;"><strong><a href="http://www.nature.com/nams/svc/myaccount/save/alert?list_id=329&WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%%LIST_ID%%-%%RECIPIENT_ID%%&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;"> Sign up for e-alerts
              </a></strong>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- end of Button -->
         <!-- Sub title -->
         <tr>
          <td width="600" align="center" class="wrapper">
           <table width="600" class="wrapper"  align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
             <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;color:#363636;padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;color:#363636;padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;"><strong>編集部が選ぶ Data Descriptors:</strong>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- end of Sub title -->
         <!-- Row 1 -->
         <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top" width="600" class="wrapper">
           <table width="600" class="wrapper" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
             <td id="gutter" width="20" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;color:#666666;"><a href="http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201535?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%25%25LIST_ID%25%25-%25%25RECIPIENT_ID%25%25&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank" style="color:#006699;text-decoration:none;"><b>The global compendium of <em>Aedes aegypti</em> and <em>Ae. albopictus</em> occurrence</b></a><br /><br /><a href="http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201519?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%25%25LIST_ID%25%25-%25%25RECIPIENT_ID%25%25&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank" style="color:#006699;text-decoration:none;"><b>A review of epidemiological parameters from Ebola outbreaks to inform early public health decision-making</b></a><br /><br /><a href="http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201516?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%25%25LIST_ID%25%25-%25%25RECIPIENT_ID%25%25&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank" style="color:#006699;text-decoration:none;"><b>A global compendium of human Crimean-Congo haemorrhagic fever virus occurrence</b></a>
            </td>
            <td id="gutter" width="20" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">&nbsp;
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td id="bottom-height" height="30" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">&nbsp;
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- End of Row 1 -->
        <!-- NPG colour bar-->
        <tr>
         <td width="600" align="right" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <table id="container" width="100%" align="right"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="right" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:20px">
             <a href="http://www.nature.com/npg_/index_npg.html?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%%LIST_ID%%-%%RECIPIENT_ID%%&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" target="_blank" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#ffffff;"><img src="http://fastart.nature.com/srep/npg_logo.gif" alt="Nature Publishing Group" width="184" height="35" border="0" align="right" style="display:block;" /></a>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- end of NPG colour bar -->
        <!-- footer-->
        <tr>
         <td width="600" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#e7e7e7">
          <table class="container" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:9px;line-height:13px;color:#666666;">
           <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="padding:25px;">As a registered user of Nature Publishing Group's Web sites, our database indicates that you have opted-in to receive product information and special offers. If you no longer wish to receive these e-mails or to discontinue all e-mail services from Nature Publishing Group please update your online account. <a href="http://www.nature.com/nams/svc/myaccount?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%%LIST_ID%%-%%RECIPIENT_ID%%&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" style="color:#666666" target="_blank"><span style="color:#666666;">Modify My Account</span></a> (Log in to be recognised as a <a href="http://www.nature.com?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%%LIST_ID%%-%%RECIPIENT_ID%%&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" style="color:#666666;" target="_blank"><span style="color:#666666;">Nature.com</span></a> registrant). <br />
            <br />
            For further information on <a href="mailto:registration@nature.com" style="color:#666666" target="_blank"><span style="color:#666666;">technical assistance</span></a> | <a href="mailto:subscriptions@nature.com" style="color:#666666" target="_blank"><span style="color:#666666;">print subscriptions</span></a> | <a style="color:#666666;" href="mailto:feedback@nature.com" target="_blank"><span style="color:#666666;">other enquiries</span></a>. <br />
            <br />
            Nature Publishing Group | Principal offices: <span style="color:#666666"><a href="http://www.nature.com/npg_/contact/offices.html?WT.mc_id=EMI_SCIDATA_1508_EpidemiologyJAPANESE&WT.i_dcsvid=%%LIST_ID%%-%%RECIPIENT_ID%%&WT.ec_id=MARKETING" style="text-decoration:none;color:#666666;" target="_blank">London | New York and Tokyo, and offices in cities worldwide including Basingstoke | Barcelona | Boston | Buenos Aires | Cairo | Delhi | Heidelberg |  Madrid | Melbourne | Mexico City | Mumbai   | Munich | Paris | San Francisco | Sao Paulo | Seoul | Shanghai and Washington DC. Macmillan Publishers Limited is a company incorporated in England &amp; Wales under company number 785998 &amp; whose registered office is located at Brunel Road, Houndmills, Basingstoke, Hampshire RG21 6XS. Nature Publishing Group | One New York Plaza, Suite 4500 | New York
            | NY 10004-1562 | US  </a></span><br />
            <br />
            <span class="symbolfix">&copy;</span> 2015 Nature Publishing Group, a division of Macmillan Publishers Limited. All rights reserved.
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <!-- end of footer -->
      </table>
      <!-- end of wrapper table -->
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- end of 100% table -->
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!!

Comment: The parent table has `width: 100%` and it contains just one column with `width: 600px`. Have you tried to add an empty extra column (without a fixed width) to allow the rest of the available space to be used up?